# Preventing variable from being reset when using state - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say we have a variable that should not be changed with react rendering. Is this possible?, without me having to use a context or raise the variable up a hierarchy in the components.

```
import React, {useState,useMemo,useRef} from 'react'

const Component=()=>{

   const [state,setState] = useState(false)
   const ref = useRef(null)

   let previous = 0

   function increment(){
       previous++
       ref.current.innerHTML = `VARIABLE: ${previous}`
   }

   return (
       <div>
           <div ref={ref}>VARIABLE: {previous}</div>
           <div>
               <button onClick={increment}>Incremente Let</button>
               <button onClick={()=>{setState(!state)}}>Change State</button>
           </div>
       </div>
    )
  }

 export default Component
```

[image]

I know I can use **state** as well, but let's see that updating the variable will trigger new renders, but the variable doesn't need to be rendered, so why a state. This code is just an example

**This example is a demonstration of the problem, not an actual implementation**

Comment: `const [previous, setPrevious] = useState(0);` then increment with `setPrevious( prev => { return prev++; })`

Comment: this is the basic principle of React. changing any state value will cause the function to run and return the updated state. "loose" variables within the function will be initialised again. This is expected behaviour. If you don't like like, go talk to facebook, they invented it that way.

Comment: After seeing the unused `useMemo` import I think the question might have to do with how can you leverage `useMemo` to optimize unnecessary re-renderings, but that would only make sense if the function is called multiple times with the same arguments, which is not the case for an ever increasing `increment` function. And also it's not particularly computationally intensive.

Comment: @Pellay https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `useRef`. The value will persist rerenders and changes will not trigger rerenders.

```
const previous = useRef(0);

function increment(){
    previous.current++;
}
```

Since modifying it won't trigger a rerender, you want to make sure you're not rendering the value.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a state variable for `previous` instead of just a plain variable. Otherwise, if not stateful, the variable will always reset on re-render.

Also there's not need for updating the `innerHTML` via ref in this case since the variable is already being rendered.

```
//...
const [previous, setPrevious] = useState(0)

function increment(){
    setPrevious(previous + 1)
}
//...
```

Comment: I'll improve my post, but I know I can use state, but it's not ideal. Let's say I don't need to render the variable, just store

Comment: I don't know why you're downvoted, however, there is no need to keep the ref to the element

Comment: @Ricardo Spinola Why wouldn't it be ideal?

Comment: I don't need the variable to be re-rendered, it's just an example, using state will cause unnecessary rendering

Comment: But when clicking on change state you are actually triggering a re-render, so I'm not really following what's the real concern here.

Comment: @RicardoSpinola You're simply trying to make react do what you think it should do. that's not the point of react.

Comment: This example is a demonstration of the problem, not an actual implementation

Comment: It's only a problem because you're saying it's a problem. A real world reason, with a demonstration, as to why this is not expected behaviour would be better than just calling it a problem.